# Need Help on SQL

Tags: sql

I actually found something that I could work on regarding my problem "Need help with sql query". But I would appreciate it if I can get an answer to my specific question.
I have 2 tables one is `TRANSACTIONS` and one is `EXPENSES`.

```
TRANSACTION:
transaction_id
emp_id
sales_date
total_sales
```

And

```
EXPENSES:
expenses_id
emp_id
expense_date
expenses1
expenses2
total_expenses
```

I would like to sum all the `TRANSACTION.transaction_amount AS sales_sum WHERE TRANSACTION.sales_date = @sales_date and TRANSACTION.emp_id = @emp_id` ..... and then, subtract the `EXPENSES.total_expenses as expenses_deducted_sales WHERE EXPENSES.emp_id = TRANSACTION.emp_id AND TRANSACTION.sales_date = EXPENSES.expense_date`

PLEASE HELP.. Thank you

Ex

```
transaction_id    emp_id   sales_date     total_sales   
1                  101     11/11/2012      300  
2                  101     11/11/2012      400  
3                  101     11/11/2012      300  

expenses_id emp_id expenses_date  expenses1  expenses2  total_expenses
1            101    11/11/2012      100        100        200
2            102    12/12/2012      50         50         100
3            103    10/12/2012      200        200        400
```

expenses_deducted_sales = (300 + 400 + 300) - 200

I've tried the code given by AHiggins and came up with these:

SELECT
CashTransactionsTbl.emp_id,
CashTransactionsTbl.trans_date,
CashTransactionsTbl.total_amt - ISNULL(ExpensesTbl.total_expenses,0) AS expenses_deducted_sales
FROM
 (
    SELECT
          emp_id,
           trans_date,
           SUM(total_amt)  AS sales_sum
     FROM CashTransactionsTbl 
     GROUP BY emp_id, trans_date
 ) tr
   LEFT JOIN
   ExpensesTbl ON
           tr.emp_id = ExpensesTbl.emp_id AND
           tr.trans_date = ExpensesTbl.trans_date
WHERE
          tr.trans_date = 2014-07-10

but no I have this error that says:

"Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

Please help!

Comment: First thing I suggest is to edit question titles so that they make some sense. "Need help with SQL query" is meaningless in a forum where every item is asking for help with SQL. Next, you have stated what you want to do; but there's nothing in your question about any problem you're running in to. What have you done? What error are you seeing? What incorrect result is returned? I.e., what **problem** do you have?

Comment: Along with that, you really need to look at your db design. An expense is a transaction. expenses1,expenses2 and total expenses would seem to be both denormalised and redundant, total_sales (total of what?) If all the data was normalised and in one table with a transaction_type, you would be in a much better place.

Comment: Im sorry about the title. I will make sense next time. I don't have errors or incorrect results yet because I do not know how to express what should happen with the data in sql syntax yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need two derived tables: One with the transaction sum per employee, one with the expenses sum per employee. Full outer join These to get all records.

```
select
  coalesce(t.emp_id, e.emp_id) as emp_id,
  coalesce(t.sum_sales, 0) as sum_sales,
  coalesce(e.sum_expenses, 0) as sum_expenses,
  coalesce(t.sum_sales, 0) - coalesce(e.sum_expenses, 0) as expenses_deducted_sales
from
(
  select emp_id, sum(total_sales) as sum_sales 
  from transaction 
  group by emp_id
) t
full outer join
(
  select emp_id, sum(total_expenses) as sum_expenses
  from expense 
  group by emp_id
) e on e.emp_id = t.emp_id;
```

Comment: This looks good but I don't know the coalesce yet. I would have to research on it. I would surely try this tomorrow at my office. Thank you!

Comment: Sir, why does it say invalid column name "total_amt", invalid column name "total_expenses" when I have these fields in my CashTransactionsTbl(total_amt) and ExpensesTbl(total_expenses)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the aggregate data from Transactions before you match that with the data from Expenses, like so:

```
SELECT  
    tr.Emp_ID,
    tr.Sales_Date,
    tr.Sales_Sum - ISNULL(Expenses.Total_Expenses,0) AS Expenses_Deducted_Sales
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
        Emp_ID,
        Sales_Date,
        SUM(Total_Sales) Sales_Sum
    FROM Transactions
  ) tr
     LEFT JOIN 
    Expenses ON 
        tr.Emp_ID = Expenses.Emp_ID AND
        tr.Sales_Date = Expenses.Expenses_Date
WHERE 
    tr.Sales_Date = @sales_date -- this could also go under the 'FROM Transactions' statement
```

Comment: Sir, I've tried the code above and substituted the values with mine like so:

Comment: @user3825246, your comment got cut short and I can't read it.  What did you try, and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty rough but something like this would work:

```
Select T_Sales.*,T_Sales.totalsales-totalexpesnses 'Expenses_deducted_sales'
from (
    select t.emp_id,sales_date,SUM(totalsales) 'totalsales'
    from #transaction t
    group by t.emp_id,sales_date
    ) T_Sales
left join #expenses e
on T_Sales.emp_id = e.emp_id
and T_Sales.sales_date = e.expenses_date
where sales_date = @sales_date
```

ps. Apologies for spelling - quick work.